# Build FAILED. error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, linker-errors

Any thoughts on where the error may be coming from?  I get this build failure message when I build my solution.  I have a MyFolder program folder that I copied and pasted and named MyFolder2 (now have two distinct folders for two programs, MyFolder and MyFolder2).  I also did a find/replace to replace all "MyFolder" with "MyFolder2"  across all files in the folder and did my best to ensure case sensitivity.  MyFolder compiled just fine. MyFolder2 produces the following message:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MyFolder2, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>Build started 2/15/2012 8:46:34 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "x64\Release\MyFolder2.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.

1>Link:
1>     Creating library x64\Release\Homework_dlls\MyFolder2.lib and object x64   
\Release\Homework_dlls\MyFolder2.exp
1>MyFolder.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class     
std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >      
MyFolder2::m_HomeworkType" (?m_HomeworkType@MyFolder2@@2V?$basic_string@DU
?$char_traits@D@std@@V?    $allocator@D@2@@std@@A)

1>x64\Release\Homework_dlls\MyFolder2.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.09
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: How is `m_HomeworkType` defined?

Comment: =(  It was not defined.  I added the definition and it now builds.  As foolish as that mistake was, you just saved me a lot of grief.